Linq.Expression issue with Expression.MemberInit when using virtual p
I have two models
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}



public class Branch
{
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
}

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Contact), "c");
var secondParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Branch), "b");
var properties = new[] { "FirstName", "BirthDate", "Branch.BranchName" };

var bindings = properties.Select(property =>
{
    if (property.Contains("."))
    {
        var parts = property.Split('.');
        var navigationProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, parts[0]);
        var nestedProperty = Expression.Property(navigationProperty, parts[1]);

        return Expression.Bind(
            typeof(Branch).GetProperty(parts[1]),
            nestedProperty
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return Expression.Bind(
            typeof(Contact).GetProperty(property),
            Expression.Property(parameter, property)
        );
    }
}).ToArray();

var newExpression = Expression.New(typeof(Contact));
var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, bindings);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Contact, object>>(memberInit, parameter);

my code is throwing an error on var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, bindings)
It thinks BranchName is part of Contact not Branch. When I debug, my binding for Branch.BranchName looks like this {BranchName = c.Branch.BranchName}
Is it not possible to query a virtual's property?
